Controlling HTML output location in Quarto
In RMarkdown, I used to control the output HTML file's location like this:
This was my RMarkdown YAML:
---
title: 'Hello'
knit: (function(input, ...) { 
  rmarkdown::render(input, output_file = '../Outputs/report.html') 
})
output:
  html_document
---

How can I achieve something similar in Quarto to specify where the generated HTML report should be saved?

You can use the output-dir argument of the quarto-cli.
In a terminal/shell:
quarto render scripts/hello.qmd --output-dir report/

Also, see this discussion on this topic on github.

Thank you. I was indeed aware that I could achieve that via the CLI, but my intent here, and that's how I did it with RMarkdown, was to do it directly from within the script. Just by knitting the script I could define where to save the output. I'm looking for something similar with Quarto. I tried output-dir: ../Outputs/report.html without sucess.
